# Which brands of wireless routers and DSL modems care about security?

Tags: security, router, wifi, gateway, adsl

Which vendors have established a strong security process during development where they educate firmware developers about security issues, arrange security engineers to review the code, accept vulnerability reports, fix any vulnerabilities found and issue timely firmware updates and advisories?

Comment: This question is really too broad for any meaningful answer. There is almost no way that any single person has worked with every single vendor out there. You might want to refine your question or risk getting it closed.

Comment: There's no need for a person to have worked with many different vendors in order to answer this question. You can evaluate the security of a product directly by talking to the firmware developers and other insiders, by looking at how the company handles vulnerabilities and so on. If you know of a single router/modem manufacturer that has established a strong security development process internally, please share your knowledge. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

Cisco and Juniper.

Everything else like netgear, linksys, Buffalo etc. are aimed at the mass market, so everything is colourful, shiny, and easy to use.  Sadly security apparently comes as a lower priority to these types.

Here's your trinary selector:

**Easy-to-use, Secure, Cheap.**

Choose two.

Comment: Cisco and Juniper are the only wireless router vendors that care about security, @Tom? Aruba, Meru and Trapeze, at the very least, would probably have something to say about that.

Comment: I've never used them. I can't say.

Comment: +! for the trinary selector. Wish more people thought this way :)

Comment: Strictly, that should read "Choose at most two."